# C++11: Are there reasons why some Regular Types should not have `std::hash` specialised?

Tags: c++, hash, regular-type, stdhash

With a Regular Type, I mean the definition of Stepanov in *Elements of Programming*, basically, that there's the concept of equality and that objects which are copies of each other compare equal.

So when you have a Regular Type `T`, and the equality relation is transitive (*a == b && b == c => a == c*), you can define a (*non-trivial*) hash function which is consistent with the definition of equality (*a == b => h(a) == h(b)*). Always.

But the standard doesn't include many [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) specialisations. E.g. [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) doesn't have one, and neither have the containers, with the notable exceptions of `vector<bool>` and `bitset`.

So I'm wondering what the design principle is here.

Or, asked differently: Are there reasons not to provide `std::hash` specialisations for your own types, provided they are regular and equality is transitive?

Comment: Sure, you can always define a hash function which is consistent: `size_t operator()(T& const) const { return 0; }` The question is, can you always define one that is good for an arbitrary type?

Comment: `vector<bool>` is not implemented as `vector` of `bool`s. It's a template specialization that relies on `int` to save several `bool`s (I assume 32). It's invariant to any template parameters (and the underlying types' `std::hash`), I think that's why a specialization is provided.

Comment: There are a number of types in the standard library that have [standing requests open](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#1025) to specialize `std::hash`

Comment: *"So when you have a Regular Type T, and the equality relation is transitive [...]"* This sounds like a lemma. Care to elaborate? I've read EoP, but I can't remember anything in it that proves it.

Comment: @dyp: No hashing in EoP, but if equality is an equivalence relation (which includes transitivity), then a hash function can be constructed that maps each equivalence class into a natural number. QED. But you don't actually need that equality is an equivalence relation. E.g. equality for floating-point types is not reflexive (*nan != nan*), yet a consistent hash function exists (`auto h(auto x) { return x == 0 ? 0 : hash_bits(&x, sizeof x); }`). But when you drop transitivity, then you cannot define a consistent hash function (at least in the cases I saw, e.g. `a == b <=> abs(a-b) < 1e-6`).

Comment: I don't quite see why the set of equivalence classes should be countable. For a finite set of values, this is obvious, but I don't think that's required for regular types. Maybe the countability of the set of values is a property of the representation? Additionally, even if it is possible to enumerate the equivalence classes, it might be impossible to find them. For example, if you write a wrapper type that wraps some opaque API which only exposes certain functions (the regular computational basis) for opaque handle types.

Comment: The set of equivalence classes is finite, thus countable, because your RAM is finite. Eo*P*, not Eo*infiniteVectorSpaces*. As for proxies: sure, if you want to hash proxies, you need to put a hash function into its computational basis. But the same is true for equality, and I assume equality exists (*regular* type). As a constructive approach: if you hash the subobjects which you compare for equality in the equality operation, possibly recursively, and in the same order (to handle `unordered_set`), then you get a consistent hash function.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes.

When a type has the following two properties I do not think you should define `std::hash`:

- There is no efficient way to consistently create a quality hash that covers **all** the data used to describe equality.
- There is no efficient and/or intuitive way to select a consistent subset of data to hash.

Comment: Actually, `std::hash<std::unordered_*>` can be implemented in *linear time*, whereas `operator==` has worst-cast *quadratic time*. Just hash individual items and use a commutative hash combiner (unsigned addition, *not* xor).

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz Never mind my first comment - if the hash function creates uniform values addition is fine. I'll see if I can find a better example type - I think my properties are fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Providing specialization for own types makes no sense, if they're template classes,
since the hash function (with high a very high probability) also depends on the
template parameters' types, which are unknown.

It there are no template parameters, or the template parameters are restricted to certain types

```
// provide no implementation to restrict all types
template<typename T> container;

// int is allowed
template<> container<int> {
    ...
}

// double is allowed
template<> container<double> {
    ...
}
```

providing a specialization of `std::hash` is possible, since the implementations of the classes (or the instanced template classes) are known, as it is for `vector<bool>` contrary to `complex<T>`.

Comment: What's wrong with `namespace std { template <typename T> struct hash<complex<T>> { using result_type = size_t; using argument_type = complex<T>; result_type operator()(const argument_type &a) const { std::hash<T> hash; size_t result = hash(a.real()) + 0x9e3779b9; result ^= hash(a.imag()) + 0x9e3779b9 + (result << 6) + (result >> 2); return result; } }; }`?

Comment: the line `std::hash<T> hash;` requires that there is a `std::hash` specialization for `T`, it uses this specialization to create a specialization for `complex<T>`, but how can one know that this would yield an effective implementation?

Comment: `complex` is only allowed to be instantiated with `float`, `double` and `long double`. Even if it wasn't, failure to provide a `hash<Custom>` when requesting instantiation of `hash<complex<Custom>>` would just yield the expected error. No problem there. And the combiner (with the magic number) is a pretty good one, from Boost, regardless of the types involved.

Comment: Sry, I rather meant efficient. Of course you're proposal is effective, at least as effective as `hash<Custom>`.

Comment: Why would a `hash<complex<Custom>>` be _at least as efficient_ as `hash<Custom>`? That makes no sense. It should be roughly 2x slower, a bit more to allow for the combining operation, a bit less to allow for instruction-level parallelism. Likewise, whether I define my `hash<complex<T>>` generically or whether I define three `hash<complex<FP>>`, `FP` in {`float`, `double`, `long double`}, there should be no difference in efficiency, should there?