# C++ Comparison operators for std::unordered_set

Tags: python, c++, hash, set, unordered

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293575/why-dont-unordered-associative-containers-implement-the-less-than-operator) post raised a question of the absence of `>`, `<` .. comparison operators for unordered containers in C++. From the reply it looks meaningless to have those. 
However, I checked Python and see that `set` type supports subset and superset operations. Python `set` is a hash table. We can easily do:

```
{'1', '6',  't', 'j'} > {'1', '6', 'j'}   # superset
True
{'1', '6', 'j', 't'} < {'1', '6', 'j'}    # subset
False
```

How to implement comparison operators in C++ for hash table (`std::unordered_set`)? Or we do have to stick to `std::set` for any comparison other than equality?

Comment: You still have the option to define your own custom relations according to your needs.

Comment: You cannot add operator overload for `std` types, because ADL will not find them (and you are not allowed to add anything to namespace `std`). You can implement a function or function object tho.

Comment: The [`std::set` uses lexicographic comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp). You could look into using [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)` to achieve the same with a `std::unordered_set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's sets have a partial order, not a total order, based on the subset relation. E.g. neither `{ 1, 2, 3 } < { 2, 3, 4 }` nor `{ 1, 2, 3 } > { 2, 3, 4 }` are true, but `{ 1, 2, 3 } == { 2, 3, 4 }` is false.

You can write a `<` that behaves like that, but as noted in the comments, you can't put it in `namespace std`, so it won't be found in some contexts.

I'd advise instead making a free function

```
template<typename UnorderedContainer>
bool is_proper_subset(const UnorderedContainer & lhs, const UnorderedContainer & rhs);
```

You could also make variations for `<=`, `>` and `>=` (respectively)

```
template<typename UnorderedContainer>
bool is_subset(const UnorderedContainer & lhs, const UnorderedContainer & rhs);

template<typename UnorderedContainer>
bool is_proper_superset(const UnorderedContainer & lhs, const UnorderedContainer & rhs);

template<typename UnorderedContainer>
bool is_superset(const UnorderedContainer & lhs, const UnorderedContainer & rhs);
```